# Can't filter objects by BooleanField in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, orm, pgadmin-4

I'm building a reminder and trying to filter Task objects by a BooleanField called 'status'.

as you can see, I have assigned Task.objects.filter(status=False) to undone_tasks, but when I run it, I get this error: ProgrammingError at /showing-all-tasks/
argument of NOT must be type boolean, not type character varying
LINE 1: ..."status", "task"."reminder" FROM "task" WHERE NOT "task"."st...

This is the query running in postgres:
SELECT "task"."id", "task"."user_id", "task"."title", "task"."slug", "task"."description", "task"."deadline_date", "task"."date_edited", "task"."status", "
task"."reminder" FROM "task" WHERE NOT "task"."status" ORDER BY "task"."deadline_date" DESC

when I change "task"."status" to "task"."status" = 'true' in pgAdmin, everything works fine! but im cofused! First of all: why do I get this error? secondly: if status is a BooleanField, why when I compare it a string('true') I don't receive any errors?

thanks for the help!

**views.py**

```
class TaskListView(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'mysite/show_tasks.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskListView, self).get_context_data()
        undone_tasks = Task.objects.filter(status=False)        
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
  # some other fields...
  status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Task Status', default=False)

class ReminderNotification(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='user', related_name='owner_notifications')
    message = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='message')
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='task',
                             related_name='task_reminder_notifications')
```

Comment: in django shell, i manually change status to booleanfield , but when i exit shell and come back again, status type is <class 'str'>!!

Comment: Was `status` perhaps changed from a `CharField` to a `BooleanField`? Does `python manage.py makemigrations --check --dry-run` show any missing migrations?

Comment: @azundo No, it was BooleanField from the begging, and when i run python manage.py makemigrations --check --dry-run, it says no changes detected

Comment: Based on your error messages, in your database the `task.status` field is of type varchar. Bit of a mystery to me how that came to be if you have no migrations and it was always a boolean however.

Comment: @azundo exaclty! i have to records in my DB, I iterated on those records and executed this:
for t in tasks:
    t.status = True
    t.save()

then i printed type(t.status) it was boolean
but after i exited django shell, i came back again and type(task.status) was str !!
don't know why that happend

Comment: Yes, the boolean is getting coerced to a string since the underlying field in the database is varchar, not boolean, so only strings can be saved there. I'm just unsure as to why the database schema doesn't match the model definition, hence my question about the migrations and wondering if `status` was once a `CharField`.

Comment: @azundo but why? i have declared status as a BooleanField. i checked the type of status in pgAdmin 4, Data Type was character varying !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:
I checked the type of "status" in pgadmin 4, it was character varying instead of Boolean, so I changed its type using the query bellow:
`ALTER TABLE task ALTER COLUMN status TYPE BOOLEAN USING status::boolean`